# vim command to search between number of keywords occurence

Tags: vim

In this file ...

```
thu klfjakldsjfkasd f thu jsdklfjkaldsfj  thu fjklasdjflasdjf  thu jfkasjdklfasd thu
thu uiuor kdsjfkasd f thu nmdasnf asdhfj  thu lopieqrefd sdjf  thu heyqewf lfasd thu
```

... I want to delete content between 1st "thu" to 3rd "thu".
Can someone help to find out the command to do so?

In vim, `thu.*thu` searches till the last occurence of the keyword.
Is there anything, where we restrict the search to number of occurrence?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

In order to match only a certain number of patterns, one needs counts as well as non-greedy multipliers. They are documented in `:help \{` and `:help non-greedy`, respectively.

In Vim, `\{-}` (or `\{-\}`) is the non-greedy cousin of `*`.
Replacing `*` with it in the question's original regexp will give `thu.\{-}thu` which will only match two consecutive "thu"s and the text inbetween. This is already close to a solution.

Next, one needs to introduce a count to match up to the third "thu". We also need to group a little bit using parentheses `\( ... \)`. The regexp `thu\(.\{-}thu\)\{2}` will match a "thu" followed by the group "anything-thu" exactly two times.

The following two lines use the `:substitute` command to replace from the first "thu" to the third "thu" with nothing, effectively deleting it. The upper line includes the delimiting "thu"s while the lower excludes them:

```
:s/thu\(.\{-}thu\)\{2}//
:s/thu\zs\(.\{-}\zethu\)\{2}//
```

The exclusive version uses `\zs` and `\ze` to delimit the start and end of the match to be operated on, see `:help \zs`.

The documentation on all the other regexp-related actions can be found with `:help regexp` in Vim.

**Edit:** next to Jens' excellent no-nonsense answer this one looks bloated, even comically so. And it is. So let's heap some more text on it...

For a one-off action, go with `d3/thu` as suggested by Jens. The strong suit of `:substitute` is to operate on a *range*, e.g. a visual selection or the whole buffer with `:%s`. Performing deletion on several lines of a huge file will be faster this way. It depends on the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a count to the `/` search command, which in turn is a movement command you can give to the delete `d` command:

- `d3/thu` - deletes up to the third thu

Note possible off-by-one: if the cursor is on a thu already, finding the third thu is the fourth.

Answer (score 1):

Quick one-liner:

```
:%s/\v.{-}thu\zs.{-}thu.{-}\zethu//
```

- `\v` makes the search "very magic"
- `{-}` is lazy repeat, just like `*?` in other regex engines
- `\zs` `\ze` mark the beginning and end of the match